# Replacement of IndexReader.lastModified(Directory d) in lucene version beyond 4

Tags: lucene

As IndexReader.lastModified(Directory d) method is deprecated in lucene 4. Can you please what should be used in place of this code.

Comment: fileModified(File directory, String name)
Returns the time the named file was last modified. [https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such method is available in the Lucene API any longer.  The [recommended approach](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#lastModified(org.apache.lucene.store.Directory)) would be, if you need this information, you should make it available through the commit data.

So when you commit to the index, set the commit data like this:

```java
Map<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();
userData.put("lastModified", String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()));
indexWriter.setCommitData(userData);
indexWriter.commit();
```

Then when you need to read the last commit time, you can get it from a `DirectoryReader`, like this:

```java
Map<String, String> userData = directoryReader.getIndexCommit().getUserData();
Date lastCommitDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(userData.get("lastModified")));
```